# How to solve Opcode error when deploying on Ganache?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to deploy to Ganache, which is running and configured and I keep getting the same error when running **truffle migrate --network development --reset**

Ganache log:

> [8:17:47 AM] (node:19312) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [Server]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
> [8:17:47 AM] Starting server with initial configuration: {"gasLimit":6721975,"gasPrice":20000000000,"hardfork":"merge","hostname":"127.0.0.1","port":8545,"network_id":5777,"default_balance_ether":1000000000000000,"total_accounts":10,"unlocked_accounts":[],"locked":false,"vmErrorsOnRPCResponse":true,"verbose":true,"flavor":"ethereum","db_path":"C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Ganache\ui\workspaces\wide-leaf\chaindata","mnemonic":"*","logDirectory":"C:\Users\*\Logs"}
> [8:17:47 AM] Ganache started successfully! [8:17:47 AM] Waiting for requests...
> [8:17:47 AM] (node:19312) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [Server]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Error message from truffle:

> Compiling your contracts...
> ===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\IERC20.solsolc-bin. Attempt #1
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\TestToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\SafeMath.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users*\TestToken\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:

- solc: 0.8.20+commit.a1b79de6.Emscripten.clang
  ⠇ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1

## Starting migrations...

> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 6721975 (0x6691b7)

## 1_initial_migration.js

### ⠏ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
Deploying 'TestToken'

*** Deployment Failed ***st from solc-bin. Attempt #1

"TestToken" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"TestToken" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:

- Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
- Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array out of bounds.
- Adding reason strings to your assert statements.

```
at C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\deployer\src\deployment.js:330:1
```

Truffle v5.9.0 (core: 5.9.0)
Node v18.16.0

This is the constructor with params:

```
uint128 private constant _initialSupply = 1_000_000_000_000_000 ether;
uint128 private constant _yearlySupplyIncrease = 10_000_000_000 ether;
uint128 private constant _reflectionFeePercentage = 1;
uint128 private constant _burnFeePercentage = 2;

constructor() {
    _totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    _balances[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
    emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _initialSupply);

    require(_totalSupply >= 0, "Error: Invalid total supply");
    require(_balances[msg.sender] == _initialSupply, "Error: Initial supply not assigned correctly");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem
changing the solc version to '0.8.0' in truffle-config.js solved the problem for me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ירדן חובב, I believe this is already set

    compilers: {
      solc: {
        version: "^0.8.0", // Use a compiler version compatible with your contract
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200,
          },

Comment: thanks i set mine to 0.8.2 and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and I fixed it by changing the emersion to london, this can be done in your truffle-config.js file in the module.exports:

```js
    // Configure your compilers
    compilers: {
      solc: {
        version: "0.8.24", // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
        // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
        settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
        //  optimizer: {
        //    enabled: false,
        //    runs: 200
        //  },
         evmVersion: "london"
        }
      }
    }
```